# LinkedIn Analytics Finder - how get Organization Name by URN?

Tags: api, analytics, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get LinkedIn Ads statistic by member company accordingly to this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#analytics-finder

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&timeGranularity=DAILY
```

So, I got a response like this:

```
{
"paging": {
    "start": 0,
    "count": 1000,
    "links": []
},
"elements": [
    {
        "clicks": 0,
        "pivot": "MEMBER_COMPANY",
        "pivotValue": "urn:li:organization:<some_org_id>",
        "impressions": 3,
        "externalWebsiteConversions": 0,
        "dateRange": {
            "start": {
                "month": 6,
                "day": 15,
                "year": 2020
            },
            "end": {
                "month": 6,
                "day": 15,
                "year": 2020
            }
        }
    },
```

But "pivotValue" in the result isn't a human-readable hence I want to transform Organization URN to Organization Name.
This article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/organizations/organization-lookup-api#retrieve-organizations
says that if I want to lookup Organization information as

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/{some_org_id}
```

then I must have role type ADMINISTRATOR for that organization. Really, I receive a "403 Forbidden" response for organizations from adAnalyticsV2 response.

I've read about Organization Search API but it was not helpful.

Please advise how I can retrieve Organization Name by Organization ID or URN?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter **pivotValue~(localizedName)** to retrieve the organization name. Example:

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2?q=analytics&dateRange.start.year=2019&dateRange.start.month=5&dateRange.start.day=28&dateRange.end.year=2019&dateRange.end.month=9&dateRange.end.day=30&timeGranularity=DAILY&accounts=urn%3Ali%3AsponsoredAccount%3A502840441&pivot=MEMBER_COMPANY&projection=(*,elements*(externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange(*),impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,pivot,pivotValue~(localizedName)))&fields=externalWebsiteConversions,dateRange,impressions,landingPageClicks,likes,shares,costInLocalCurrency,pivot,pivotValue
```

More info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting#requesting-specific-metrics-in-the-analytics-finder

Comment: Thank you very much, Adriele! It resolves my problem in fact.